# SSH Linux server does not execute all commands properly

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, putty

I connect to my webserver with Putty through SSH + password and wanted to generate a pair of keys to do the login for me. Unfortunately, the command gets somehow 'stuck'.. as you can see on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kL6l.png)

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: You pressed enter, right? :/

Comment: Yes, of course :D and then i keep waiting and waiting... _Why do i get a down vote?_

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text.  Just post the text here in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are first connecting to the remote server and then generating keys.  Don't do that!  Your private key should never leave your local system.  You should generate your keys locally using, e.g., [puttygen](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen), and then put the generated public key into your `authorized_keys` file on the remote host.

Comment: +1. just use the tools that come with putty to set up keys for pubkey auth.

Answer (score -1):

This is a script I use to generate SSH keys.
Give it a try.

```
#!/bin/sh

KEY="$HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub"

if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub ];then
  ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa -N ''
fi

if [ -z $1 ];then
    echo " "
    echo "Usage: $0 {user@remote.host}"
    echo "  "
    echo "  The 'user' is the remote user account allowed to authenticate to"
    echo "  the 'remote.host'."
    echo "  "
    echo "  This ssh connection is used once to copy your key to the 'remote.host'"
    echo "  "
    exit
fi

echo "Sending your key to $1... "

KEYCODE=`cat $KEY`
ssh -q $1 "mkdir ~/.ssh 2>/dev/null; chmod 700 ~/.ssh; echo "$KEYCODE" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

echo "done!"
```